# What is difference between two error messages in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Just wanted to understand difference between below two error messages.
We have upgraded spring-boot version `2.3.9 to 2.5.12` and from `org.springframework:spring-web:5.2.9.RELEASE` to`org.springframework:spring-web:5.3.18`

> Required String parameter 'search' is not present

> Required request parameter 'search' for method parameter type String is not present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message was [improved](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/1a9556925def8a0ad6f8e9c257dd9112e3379872) in Spring Framework 5.3.16. The updated message (the second in your question) provides more information about what was missing and the method parameter to which it was being bound.